# unhandled exception error when using Fontsize, FontAttributes and HorizontalOptions

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Code below is breaking for some reason but when I remove FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
         HorizontalOptions="Center", it works fine. It throws an unhandled exception and i cant deploy to the emulator. why?

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="GrouppedList"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Rss.channel.item}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding title}" Detail="{Binding description}"   FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />             
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAttributes, FontSize and HorizontalOptions are not properties of a TextCell. If you want to customize it further you will need to go to a ViewCell.

Comment: It is strange because i dont receive any Compile error on VS but only when i start deploying to the Emulator, it throws and exception and it took me hour to figure out this as exception also didnt have any specific information.

Comment: Unless you use XamlC, Xaml is compiled at runtime, not build. I assumed you could build it but then it failed when trying to run.